# c++ function call via pointer can acess hidden base class member function?

Tags: c++, virtual

I have the code as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Base
{
public:
        virtual int f(int i);   // _ZN4Base1fEi
};

int Base::f(int i)
{
        cout << "Base f()" << endl;
}

class Derived:public Base
{
public:
        // (change) int f(int p);
        int f(int *p);
};
// (change) int Derived::f(int p)
int Derived::f(int *p)
{
        cout << "Derived f()" << endl;
}

int main(void)
{
        Base b;
        Derived d;

        Base *pa, *pb;

        pa = &b;
        pb = &d;

        pa->f(1);   // Base f()
        pb->f(1);   // Base f()
        //d.f(1);   // compile error!
        return 0;
}
```

If I use the `(change)` code instead, the output will be

```
Base f()
Derived f()
```

So `(change)` code is overloading `Base::f()`, and for the function call, I think compiler should generate something like this:

```
(*pa->vptr[1])(pa, 1)    // access vtbl to get function address
(*pb->vptr[1])(pb, 1)
```

This is because compiler knows that `Base::f()` and `Derived::f()` are virtual functions, right? So it generates the code to acess vtbl. 
But if not using `(change)` code, both calls to `f()` will access `Base::f()`, does that mean it still generates the same as above to access vtbl? If it's ture, can I assume the process to generate code is as follows:
for the function call via pointer, check the referenced type of pointer (`pa` or `pb`) first, and think of `f()` as `<reference type>::f()` (`Base::f()` here), found it is a virtual function and generate the code. 
This will lead to another question, `Derived::f()` hides `Base::f()` in `class Derived`, that is why `d.f(1)` is an error. But `pb->f(1)` can acess `Base::f()`, and `pb` points to `Derived d`, does this mean `pb->f(1)` can access the hidden `Base::f()`? So hide mechanism doesn't working for function call via pointer?

Thanks

Comment: The first call will be virtual, but the second wont be because int f(int *p) is not a virtual function. d.f(1) is an error because f(int*) hides the definition of f(int)

Comment: `int f(int*)` does not override the virtual function declared in `Base`, so `pb->f(1)` will default to the base class function. `d.f(1)` is an error because `Derived::f(int*)` *hides* Base's `Base::f(int)`. Throw in a using statement to make it work. `using Base::f`

Comment: You have a big mess in your head and you overcomplicated it. You need to understand what happens at compile time and runtime.

Answer (score 1):

> This is because compiler knows that Base::f() and Derived::f() are virtual functions, right?

Not quite. Compiler knows that `Base::f()` is virtual, if `Derived::f()` is virtual or not, hides it or not is irrelevant in this case. You created bad example and made it to confuse yourself. Look at this function:

```
void f( Base *p )
{
     p->f(1);
}
```

and try to answer your own questions looking into it. Also try to answer this:

1 Does compiler know if `p` points to `Base` or `Derived`?

2 If it does not, how it would generate code to call `f()`?

> So hide mechanism doesn't working for function call via pointer?

Hide mechanism is compile time concept, and works for resolving method call. You call `f()` through pointer to `Base *`, so compiler does not care if it is hidden in `Derived` or not, it generated code to call virtual method through `Base` pointer.

In reality in your case optimizer may eliminate virtual table resolution as it knows actual types, but result will be exactly the same. And it is completely unrelated to "hiding mechanism"

Comment: the example was created when I tried to figure out hiding mechanism, and I got confused if the virtual function in base class was hidden or not, so I just posted the code. Your two questions are helpful for me to make things clear. Compiler doesn't know if `p` points to `Base` or `Derived`, it only sees `p` is `Base *` and `Base::f()` is virtual, so it generates code using vptr, right?

Comment: For `pb->f(1)`, the function called was `Base::f()` inherited from `class Base`, this happens at runtime, compared to `d.f(1)`, which is a compile error, can I say that `Base::f()` inherited from base class can be called via pointer to derived class object but can't be called via derived class object?

Answer (score 0):

Overloading only applies to names defined in the same scope. So the version of `f` in the base class and the version of `f` in the derived class are not overloads, and that's why the call to `d.f(1)` fails: there is no version of `f` that takes an `int`, because the compiler stops looking when it finds `f(int*)` in `Derived`.

The reason that the other calls works is that they're going through pointers to `Base`, and the only version of `f` in `Base` takes an `int`, so that's the one that's called.

This has nothing to do with virtual functions. It would work the same way if `Base::f` was not virtual, or if `Derived::f` was virtual.